# make apps for iphone 5 and iphone 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone-4, iphone-5

Hi I have the next question who do i develop for iphone 5 and iphone 4 screen size 
with iOS `4.3 ++` support, do I have to create  `2 UI` for **screen size 3.4** and other **for 4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having any trouble on updating your app to fit the new iPhone 5 configuration please consider at least reading this: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/ and than you can ask here on StackOverflow more specific questions about any problem you're having.